# Spark metadata size increasing in spark streaming job

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

I am running spark streaming job and saving data to hdfs as orc file format.Spark is creating metadata for the same and it keep increasing which in result failing of job due to heap memory issue [when medatadata .compact file size reach to 300MB].

**Workaround I adopted**-Delete the metadata folder and checkpointing directory and start the job.

is there any soln so that we can purge the metadata without restarting  the job

Comment: I am also struggling to find solution for this for long now.